The flat structure definition in A primer on mapping class groups
I am unsure about the definition of a flat structure used in A primer on mapping class groups.
The phrase flat structure appears twice throughout the book and, for a torus, is treated as some $\phi: T^2 \rightarrow X.$
What I've read in the book is that a surface is called flat, if it has an Euclidean metric, which is said to be a complete, finite-area Riemannian metric on a surface with constant, vanishing curvature and totally geodesic boundary.
I know a definition of a flat structure as a $(Isom(\mathbb{R}^2), \mathbb{R}^2)$-structure (a special case of a $(G,X)$-structure).
What I believe is probable, is that $X$ is a Riemannian manifold with a flat metric in the sense of the bolded text, the torus is just a smooth manifold without any Riemannian metric until we obtain it by a diffeomorphism $\phi$ by a pullback.
Is any of these the definition I should embrace? If not, I'd be euphoric to learn which is.

What you wrote as a definition of a flat structure is insufficient. Most likely, they meant a flat metric of unit area on the torus together with a "marking" (homotopy class of some homeomorphism).
